# Whether can use a URL to specify that a domain should be resolved to special IP address?

Tags: dns, browser, http

we can use curl to specify a fixed IP for a domain, when I download a resource:

```
curl -vo 1 'https://example.com/aaa/bbb/ccc.mp4' --resolve example.com:443:1.1.1.1
```

is there any way to specify a fixed IP by given URL?

such as when I visit the URL in browser:

```
https://example.com/aaa/bbb/ccc.mp4?xxxxxxx=1.1.1.1
```

then example.com DNS is resolved to 1.1.1.1

or whether only can use any downloader to implement it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no standard URL syntax for doing so.

In browsers, you might be able to find add-ons which can redirect to a different IP address.

There are many ways to override an IP address for an entire domain – /etc/hosts, or a custom DNS server with override support (Unbound, Dnsmasq), or an HTTP proxy (Privoxy), or a SOCKS proxy – but all of them involve external mechanisms as well, and none of them work with individual URLs when HTTPS is in use, only with whole domains.